# Customizing Parse Login in Swift

Tags: swift, authentication, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

I'm using Parse for the first time and have got the basic functionality working, but can't seem to customize the login form. Basically, I just want to change the title (Currently it is "Parse") and remove the "x" close button at the top left hand corner.  The code I'm using is below, any help appreciated

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {

        var logInViewController = PFLogInViewController()
        logInViewController.title = "New Title"

        logInViewController.delegate = self

        var signUpViewController = PFSignUpViewController()

        signUpViewController.delegate = self

        logInViewController.signUpController = signUpViewController

        self.presentViewController(logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else {

        self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()
        self.fetchAllObjects()

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey.  It's been some time, and I think my answer addressed your question.  Mind giving me the checkmark?

Comment: The checkmark will come to you when you're ready for the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Next time, it would be better if you could take a closer look at the documentation; both of these things are explicitly covered in the Parse docs.

These are the UI elements given by the Parse login template

[image]

To select which elements you want to toggle, simply configure and pick the fields element of the login controller.

```
logInController.fields = (PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword
                       | PFLogInFields.LogInButton
                       | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton
                       | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten
                       | PFLogInFields.DismissButton)
```

In this case, you need to remove the DismissButton field, so just remove that.

To change the Parse logo, you need to subclass PFLogInViewController:

```
class MyLogInViewController : PFLogInViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    let logoView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"logo.png"))
    self.logInView.logo = logoView
  }
}
```

and then assign it to the signUpController

```
let logInController = MyLogInViewController()
logInController.signUpController = MySignUpViewController()
self.presentViewController(logInController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

For further customization, take a look at the [Parse docs.](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#user-interface)

Comment: Thanks Mike! That was very helpful. Unfortunately not much of the docs are in swift

Comment: No problem.  Just so you know, they have rewritten all of their docs in swift.  Just click the swift button next to obj c on any of the code snippets